# Is it possible to mark a variable such that it will only be used once?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
const a = initialValue()
const b = f(a)
const c = g(b)
```

I want to do something such that when `a` is being referenced the second time, it will be a compile error.

```
const d = h(a) // Compile error: `a` can be only referenced once
```

I need this to prevent faulty value derivation from variables that I'm not supposed to use anymore.

Thus, I'm wondering if this is possible in TypeScript (during compile-time)? If not are there any alternatives that I can consider?

Extra nodes: the main reason I need this feature is to breakdown a very long value derivation process to **improve code readability**.

Imagine the value derivation is something like this:

```
const finalValue = q(w(e(r(t(y(u(i(o(p(a(s(d(f(g(h(j(k)))))))))))))))))))
```

It's obviously necessary to break it down into several sections, that's why I need temporary variables that should be only use once **within the same scope**.

Edit: Added a realistic example

```
type Point = {x: number, y: number}
const distance = (a: Point, b: Point): number => {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2))
}
```

Obviously the `distance` function above is not too readable, so I break it down by introducing temporary variable.

```
const distance = (a: Point, b: Point): number => {
  const xDistance = Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2)
  const yDistance = Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2)
  return Math.sqrt(xDistance + yDistance)
}
```

But then I have another problem, I don't these variables to be used more than once, in this case `xDistance` and `yDistance`. Referencing them more than once will introduce bug.

For example, referencing `xDistance` more than once introduces logical error which cannot be detected by type checking:

```
const distance = (a: Point, b: Point): number => {
  const xDistance = Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2)
  const yDistance = Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2)
  return Math.sqrt(
    xDistance + 
    xDistance // should be `yDistance` 
  ) 
}
```

Comment: But why? If you declare a variable and then don't use it, why did you even declare it?

Comment: I need that to breakdown a very long derivation process to improve **code readability**, for example I can of course do `const a = f(g(b))`, but imagine if this is 10 times longer it wouldn't be readable.

Comment: That's true, but you could also make a separate *function* that calculates `f(g(b))` instead. Not a variable. As I could see it in this context, a variable will store a value, but a function will store a calculation that produces a value. It seems you want the latter.

Comment: @BartHofland if I do that, I will face the same problem for that function I create

Comment: So you DO want to reuse the variable? But only "temporary"? Then I guess you should put the code that uses variable `a` in its own function. When the function is done, the variable will simply go out of scope...

Comment: @BartHofland it's not for the purpose of reuse in this case. Also, it doesn't mean that if a variable is not to be reused it's not suppose to be created.  
To make code readable, it's always normal to breakdown big function into a few smaller functions, although those function will only be used once.  
Reference: https://martinfowler.com/articles/class-too-large.html

Comment: Making code readable is very good. Functions should not only be small, they should also have a single purpose, which is reflected in the function's name, so that code will become self-explanatory. I agree with that very much. But I guess that we have an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) at hand here. Requiring a check to avoid repeated access to any created variables (for whatever reason) seems to be a kind of "code smell" to me. So instead, I would suggest to rethink your larger code structure/design to realise your goals.

Comment: @BartHofland I can't disprove you that we are having an XY-Problem here, but I believe it's not, please check at my question again, I've added a realistic example. If you will please show me how to make it more readable without introducing one-use variable.

Comment: Yes, of course. I re-read your question and I will try to provide you an example in a separate answer, if that is OK with you.

Comment: @BartHofland thanks I don't mind having another separate answer

Comment: I just looked at your `distance` examples. I don't see why your `distance` function could not be called multiple times. It's a striking example of a pure function. It will always return the same result if you supply the same arguments. So I don't see the problem here... Variables `xDistance` and `yDistance` cannot be accessed from outside the `distance` function and they will be recalculated in subsequent calling the `distance` function...

Comment: @BartHofland When did I mention that `distance` function shouldn't be call multiple times? I'm talking about the one-use variables `xDistance` and `yDistance` shouldn't be reused.  Anyway maybe it's my lack of clarification, so I edited my question again to include more explanations

Comment: I see. Well, as far as I know, those `xDistance` and `yDistance` variables will simply go out of scope after a call to `distance` and thus they will be removed from the computer's memory. When the `distance` function is called a subsequent time, those variables will be re-created and initialized anew. Mind that the `const` keyword does not keep the variable in memory. In TypeScript, the `const` keyword just signals the compiler that the variable cannot be changed after initialization. (So actually it's just a kind of `readonly let`.)

Comment: @BartHofland Yes, of course they will go out of scope after being invoked, my concern is that how to prevent them from being accidentally re-used within the same scope. I have provided an example for this in the last section of my question (just edited).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend some sort of `pipe` to compose functions in a readable manner:

```
increment(increment(multiply(2)(toLength("foo")))) // 8
```

becomes

```
flow(
  toLength,
  multiply(2),
  increment,
  increment
)("foo") // 8
```

This will prevent temporary variables, as [@Bart Hofland said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61769648/5669456), while keeping code clean.

[Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=70&ssc=20&pln=75&pc=9#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMANnA7gHgIKIKYAeUeYAJgM6IBKeAhqQigJ7YBOrtTm4A1mBmAB8AGkQAhQQApaAIwBciSQDoVtBdgCUiALyDxGhctXqtu8QFgAUKEiwEyNFlyFiZSjXqMW7TtzB8BEXFRAGEpWUMVJTVETR09MVEZCEN5fXjEEINFKJi4sxCrG2h4JFQMHHwiEgpqOgYwZjYOLl5%20dCFRRMzRABEpK0RECJzjWNME4UHEZNSFMQme6YhSQxTMxd6rbKNokwyt63AS%203KnKtdajwamn1b-ds7gnsRe0QBRAcshkd28xcS01mijSCwyISm30QKzWCiyB0hQ1IeEMq1ei3e20iY3yekxR1spQcGEk0xGADFjnYwIiZhAAPwKSmEhC0laMxDMk406bIjlc6m0vDAflU0q04AAc1FLJ5UMlAAsZdzaQqYMrBdMYAArDWlLGINoCRAAb2m5HQMCgEAVilorElIAAtiQoOQlCgSJKoAqtGaoUMILRyHhEABGOTTIZDVh4KAgVhIWRR6HB0MAJkjAejsfjieQYvskh9MHICiNHT9KejiFzCaQyQAhNIZNEAA5t5jFtXkUT2x0usBujQaauIAC%20KaDIcQAGYszWY3H6wXZYoS2XDQ8BFXszW6-mVs2my3252mN3S32Hc7XeQR6O9xOp2nEAAWBeLg9lQtIS%20biswF3Rcc2XfNkWbI9JBPWQzy7DdrwHO8H0fEDJ2zadQwAVk-fcwJ-Nd-3LbdK1NMclzzJBhWbCDJCgmDW1oDt4J7RDbyHe8ULHdCa0wxAADZcNAyjV25dce2IgJSP9ECKJXKVm2oyRaPoiBm1gpjz3-NjB2HFDUMXHjoz4gB2IS5PzYpqXE0tJMeYDZO-RBFWbBTJCUlTSGPNTT00lir2GG9dM4-TuJfGcAA5zNrfDROsoitykoCyKfCykDVZsXMkNyPLwSCvOgnyNOYi8EMCpCOP0h8wow18AE5oqcqyiQSwCHJApydWbDLJCynLgBovK6IKhi4NK1jyvYvSqoMmsjKM78rHQqwIAQcgoEQKA4AAGS9H0dEUTd1tYGAwElRZ3U9M6fRWtaNqdEAUFgc8DuLGAXU3MBnRkPBWEWSQwAUL6nR%20v6MiQAAqTb3rwchbrAdbEFOiBY1017AcQYHQcWJAAGpwyseHEdjchHo27QkcgVHXUkZHqaHSQHqemAtPTDRix2vaFUkAAiYA4DgHmuMsImNpJsmAAUWdDCmzlJKEtt266FVpJnnq7NnaTpvBdK1qmdddbZef5wXHyJuBPQ9OBJUkcWntEO2oClts8A0IA)
(this is the `flow` implementation from [fp-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/12c5f51/src/function.ts#L142-L248) library)

---

If you really (really) need something like a compile-time check for a "one-time" variable :

```
type UsedFlag = { __used__: symbol } // create a branded/nominal type 
type AssertNotUsed<T> = T extends UsedFlag ? "can be only referenced once" : T

const a = 42 // a has type 42
const b = f(a)
markAsUsed(a)
a // now type (42 & UsedFlag)
const d = h(a) // error: '42 & UsedFlag' is not assignable '"can be only referenced once"'.

function markAsUsed<T>(t: T): asserts t is T & UsedFlag {
    // ... nothing to do here (-:
}

function f(a: number) { }
function h<T>(a: AssertNotUsed<T>) { }
```

[Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhAJgMQDYEMDmUC8UDeUA%20kQK4KIkBcUcIAtgEYD2qUAvlAPRdQDGAJwjpg0dFEYD0AO0RIu05vQCW09G1CQoAWABQm6AEE4CAcAByzYPCQAeACoA%20XFHtQIAD1Gy4sCmiwoAH4oACI%20GQloZmlUECghADMIIWk%20JCgY9NCoGns9PT4YuGAocTwAFgAmbl5xAAt0XwMoasLi0sYXRIAKdABKPXp0AQBrYxtEPsHdcR4oRQB3KBae6qgAMj8kAMwZoukSqEQXeuna9wEBZgEaAHJ1rcndu6hlX0VSprhlTDVGVDQO7hSKMaKxeJJFIQNIZLIQUJ3AB0BV0iVIaWAyhiUGGYwmFAcjh6wDy-Ro3xSwGab18bie-gw2HweigbIuSM5Cys9VU2GAzGOgvq0KgPQAtFQ9OxUejMdjpFBeugaNJSEwUv0CBw9HK%20FicfUiX0aMZTBYrJMiVrCOwgA)

Comment: Wow so it's really doable in TypeScript. This is amazing!

Comment: Interesting answer. I will go study it. Thanks. :) I was already thinking about looking into RxJS to work more explicitly with functional reactive programming concepts, but this is a good tip as well.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have a reason for creating the variable; otherwise, [Bart Hofland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61769648/157247) is on-point.

I suspect you can't (but then, just about every time I think that about TypeScript, I learn I'm wrong).

But there's a way (perhaps a hack) you can do it with object properties:

```
const v = {
    a_value: initialValue(),
    get a() {
        if (this.a_used) {
            throw new Error("a has already been used");
        }
        this.a_used = true;
        return this.a_value;
    }
};

// ...
const b = f(v.a); // Works
// ...
const d = h(v.a); // Fails: "a has already been used"
```

If you're going to do that more than once (which seems likely), you can use a helper function:

```
function oneTime(obj: object, name: string, value: any) {
    let used = false;
    Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
        get() {
            if (used) {
                throw new Error(`${name} has already been used`);
            }
            used = true;
            return value;
        }
    });
    return obj;
}

// ...

const v = {};
oneTime(v, "a", initialValue());
const b = f(v.a); // Works
// ...
const d = h(v.a); // Fails: "a has already been used"
```

You can make it even more convenient to use if you build it in a proxy:

```
function oneTimer() {
    const used = new Set<string | Symbol>();
    return new Proxy({}, {
        get(target: object, name: string | Symbol) {
            if (used.has(name)) {
                throw new Error(`${String(name)} has already been used`);
            }
            used.add(name);
            return target[name];
        }
    });
}


const v = oneTimer();
v.a = initialValue();
v.b = f(v.a);
v.c = g(v.b);
v.d = h(v.a); // Error: a has already been used
```

Live Example:

```js
function oneTimer() {
    const used = new Set/*<string | Symbol>*/();
    return new Proxy({}, {
        get(target/*: object*/, name/*: string | Symbol*/) {
            if (used.has(name)) {
                throw new Error(`${String(name)} has already been used`);
            }
            used.add(name);
            return target[name];
        }
    });
}


const v = oneTimer();
v.a = initialValue();
v.b = f(v.a);
v.c = g(v.b);
console.log(v.c);
v.d = h(v.a); // Error: a has already been used


















function initialValue() {
    return 42;
}
function f(n) {
    return n * 2;
}
function g(n) {
    return n / 2;
}
function h(n) {
    return n * 3;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for compile-time checking instead of run-time checking, but thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: @WongJiaHau - Yeah, this is definitely a "if you can't get what you want, you can use this hack" kind of answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to reuse a variable, simply don't create it. Instead, use the expression that you use to initialize the variable where you use(d) the variable itself.

```
const b = f(initialValue())
const c = g(b)
```

A variable is traditionally used for storing values for reuse. If you don't want that, don't use them.

Comment: I sort of assumed the OP had a reason for the variable, but it makes sense not to leave this unsaid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've edited my question to include the reason

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my earlier answer, I propose a possible solution to solve the `a` variable access issue for you.

In your answer, you gave this example:

```
const finalValue = q(w(e(r(t(y(u(i(o(p(a(s(d(f(g(h(j(k)))))))))))))))))))
```

Suppose the value of `a(s(d(f(g(h(j(k)))))))` should be calculated once and reused in functions `q`, `w`, `e`, `r`, `t`, `y`, `u`, `i`, `o`, and `p`.

Then you would get something like this:

```
const x = a(s(d(f(g(h(j(k)))))))
const finalValue = q(w(e(r(t(y(u(i(o(p(x))))))))))))
```

Now suppose you want to avoid that variable `x` is accessed again:

```
const x = a(s(d(f(g(h(j(k)))))))
const finalValue = q(w(e(r(t(y(u(i(o(p(x))))))))))))
const trySomething = x  // This should fail, because x is already accessed for calculating finalValue!
```

In that case, I would create a separate function, say `calculate`, to perform the complex calculation (bookmark 1):

```
function calculate(k) {
  const x = a(s(d(f(g(h(j(k)))))))
  return q(w(e(r(t(y(u(i(o(p(x))))))))))))
}

const finalValue = calculate(k)
```

As you can see here, variable `x` is now only accessible within function `calculate` for the purpose of the complex calculation.

However, there is no way to avoid calling the `calculate` function multiple times. Each time, variable `x` will be re-calculated as well. If you want to avoid that, you could use a variable to check if function `calculate` is already executed (bookmark 2):

```
let calculated = false;
function calculate(k) {
  if (calculated) {
    throw new Error('Do not call me again!')
  }

  calculated = true
  const x = a(s(d(f(g(h(j(k)))))))
  return q(w(e(r(t(y(u(i(o(p(x))))))))))))
}

const finalValue = calculate(k)
const finalValue2 = calculate(k) //Will throw error
```

But it might be possible to manipulate the `calculated` variable here. Using first-class functions (functions that return functions) and closures might help you in that case (bookmark 3):

```
function generate_calculate_function() {
  let calculated = false;

  return function(k) {
    if (calculated) {
      throw new Error('Do not call me again!')
    }

    calculated = true
    const x = a(s(d(f(g(h(j(k)))))))
    return q(w(e(r(t(y(u(i(o(p(x))))))))))))
  }
}

const calculate = generate_calculate_function();
const finalValue = calculate(k)
const finalValue2 = calculate(k) //Will throw error
```

The generated `calculate` function can now be called only once. And there is no way to manipulate the `calculated` variable from the outside.

However, there is now no restriction on generating a second `calculate` function and use that instead:

```
const calculate = generate_calculate_function();
const finalValue = calculate(k)

const calculate2 = generate_calculate_function();
const finalValue2 = calculate2(k) // Fine
```

So in the end, there will be no way to avoid calculating the value of variable `x` inside the `calculate` function multiple times.

But in my opinion, there should be no need to avoid multiple calculations at all. It should technically not be an issue to call function `calculate` multiple times. Or does the function have side effects and should your program thus be used only once and then never again? In that case, I would simply add some initial logic that somehow checks if your program has already been run in the past and only continue if that is not the case. Or better yet: I would try to separate the "pure" (repeatable) logic from the "unpure" (side-effects) logic and put any necessary run-once checks in that "unpure" logic, so that it will be skipped in subsequent calls. (This is an example of what I meant in my comment for you to consider rethinking your code structure/design.)

So I personally would just go with the code under bookmark 1 above. As I see it, the value of `x` is only used within the scope that needs it (the logic of function `calculate`) and it cannot be falsely used anywhere else.

NB:
My solutions also use run-time checks. As far as I know, there is no way to let the compiler check if (and disallow that) a variable or function is being accessed multiple times.